# Help with a javascript onclick command to allow only one click and disallow multiple clicks on a submit button

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am building a quiz program from the tutorial:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/14/creating-a-quiz-web-application-using-sharepoint-designer-part-4.aspx

In it, I use a submit button with the code:

```
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="javascript     {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={ShowQuestion.aspx?Title=',$URL1,'&amp;Question=',$NextQNumber,'&amp;Of=',$URL2,'&amp;Session=',$URL3,'}'))}" />
```

Unfortunately, users are able to click-through and submit to the answers list multiple times for the same question, because there is no limit to the number of clicks/submissions per page.  After Googling I saw two main options.  One is to put some more code in, as shown in this link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926816/how-to-prevent-multiple-form-submit-from-client-side) while the other is to change the button to a loading button that is dead when pressed the first time.  Unfortunately, I am unsure of how to do either for my lines of code.  I understand it can be tough to call multiple functions within a single command, so I've been intimidated by that.  Please try to recommend a fix for this or more information regarding the solutions given.  I unfortunately have no experience coding in javascript before this tutorial.

Comment: Have you considered cookies? Though they can be deleted, it's the only client-side tool you can use to prevent multiple submits to the same quiz by the same users.

Comment: I have considered cookies, but was discouraged because of (like you mentioned) their ease of deletion.  Considering that my users are Microsoft authenticated and I have already set up the ability to pull the unique login name of the user I believed I could moderate their clicking.  

I was thinking of a script like:
`onclick add one to a variable`
`if variable <1 submit like normal`
`else terminate button functionality`

but am unsure of javascript's ability to do that type script.

Answer (score 1):

u can user jquery to disable the button after its clicked 
import jquery  to your page ... at the end of the page add an eventhandel

$(yourbuttonid).click(function(this){this.disable();});
somthing like that should do it

Comment: Would this require jquery to be installed on users' computers or could it be included somewhere in my page's script and it call on a server that hosts the jquery language code?